# How to record video of MediaElement item in xaml (UWP)

Tags: xaml, stream, uwp, mediaelement

How to record video of MediaElement item in xaml (UWP)

I have MediaElement that stream its video from url

And I want to record some minutes of this MediaElement , there are any tutorial help me ?

P.S : Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to record some minutes of this MediaElement , there are any tutorial help me ?

[`MediaElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) cannot be recorded directly. If you know the media original source file, you could create [`MediaClip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) for several minutes you want to record and save to make it "recorded". For example,  you could get the start recording  position of `MediaElement`  to calculate the [`TrimStartTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Transcoding.MediaTranscoder#Windows_Media_Transcoding_MediaTranscoder_TrimStartTime) for clip, and same as `TrimStopTime`, then save the clip to [`MediaComposition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Editing.MediaComposition) so that the clip can be rendered to a new file. Details for how to do please reference [Media compositions and editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-compositions-and-editing) and the scenario 2  of the [MediaEditing official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MediaEditing).

In additionally,`MediaClip` can be created from file by `CreateFromFileAsync(IStorageFile)`, if you need to create clips for the media stream from website you may need to download it firstly.